# Ubuntu Core switch WiFi between AP and STA

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, access-point, snap

I’m using Ubuntu Core and I’m new to Snappy.

I’m using the snap package “wifi-ap” to enable Access Point. I’m also using “NetworkManager” when I want to use Station mode.

I’m struggling to switch from AccessPoint to Station and vis versa.
Currently the only way I found to switch between modes is to enable or disable wifi-ap with :

```
sudo wifi-ap.config set disabled=false
```

or

```
sudo wifi-ap.config set disabled=true
```

and then restart the system.

Do you know if there is a procedure documented somewhere ?

If not I can give more details about what I tried and what errors I got.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to switch between modes without rebooting by reloading the kernel driver :

```
$ sudo modprobe -r ven_rsi_sdio
$ sudo modprobe ven_rsi_sdio
```